# Figure gets cut/doesnt pass to next page

Tags: graphics, figure-placement

Here's the code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw
        (0,0) coordinate(v0) {} 
        (v0)--++(0,2) coordinate(v2)
        (v2)--++(2,0) coordinate(v3)
        (v3)--++(0,-2) coordinate(v4)
        (v4)++(-2,0) coordinate(v5)
        
        (v4)--(v5) node[pos=0.5,below=0.2cm]{Subestação 1}
        
        (v0)++(4,3) coordinate(v6)
        (v6)--++(2,1) coordinate(v7)

        (v0)++(1.8,1.5) coordinate(v8)
        (v8)--++(1,-0.3) coordinate(v9)

        (v9)--++(-1,-0.7) coordinate(v10)
        (v9)--++(-1,-0.4) coordinate(v11)

        (v9)--++(4,0.1) coordinate(v12)
        (v12)--++(4,0.5) coordinate(v13)

        (v13)++(0.5,-1.75) coordinate(v14) {}
        (v14)--++(0,3) coordinate(v15)
        (v15)--++(1,0) coordinate(v16)
        (v16)--++(0,-3) coordinate(v17)
        (v17)--++(-1,0) coordinate(v18)
        (v17)--(v18) node[pos=0.5,below=0.1cm]{Subestação 2}


        (v0)++(2.5,0.1) coordinate(v20)
        (v20)--++(1,0.3) coordinate(v21)
        (v21)--++(8,0.2)
        ;

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.} 
        \vspace{0.03\textwidth}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw
        (0,0) coordinate(v0) {} 
        (v0)++(0,2) coordinate(v2)
        (v2)++(2,0) coordinate(v3)
        (v3)++(0,-2) coordinate(v4)
        (v4)++(-2,0) coordinate(v5);
        \draw [blue] (v0)--(v2);
        \draw [blue] (v2)--(v3);
        \draw [blue] (v3)--(v4);
        \draw [blue] (v4)--(v5) node[pos=0.5,below=0.2cm]{Subestação 1};

        \draw
                
        (v0)++(4,3) coordinate(v6)
        (v6)--++(2,1) coordinate(v7)

        (v0)++(1.8,1.5) coordinate(v8)
        (v8)--++(1,-0.3) coordinate(v9)

        (v9)--++(-1,-0.7) coordinate(v10)
        (v9)--++(-1,-0.4) coordinate(v11)

        (v9)--++(4,0.1) coordinate(v12)
        (v12)--++(4,0.5) coordinate(v13)

        (v13)++(0.5,-1.75) coordinate(v14) {}
        (v14)--++(0,3) coordinate(v15)
        (v15)--++(1,0) coordinate(v16)
        (v16)--++(0,-3) coordinate(v17)
        (v17)--++(-1,0) coordinate(v18)
        (v17)--(v18) node[pos=0.5,below=0.1cm]{Subestação 2}
        
        (v0)++(2.5,0.1) coordinate(v20)
        (v20)--++(1,0.3) coordinate(v21)
        (v21)--++(8,0.2)
        ;

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.} 
        \vspace{0.03\textwidth}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw
        (0,0) coordinate(v0) {} 
        (v0)++(0,2) coordinate(v2)
        (v2)++(2,0) coordinate(v3)
        (v3)++(0,-2) coordinate(v4)
        (v4)++(-2,0) coordinate(v5);
        \draw [blue] (v0)--(v2);
        \draw [blue] (v2)--(v3);
        \draw [blue] (v3)--(v4);
        \draw [blue] (v4)--(v5) node[pos=0.5,below=0.2cm]{Subestação 1};

        \draw
        (v0)++(4,3) coordinate(v6)
        (v6)++(2,1) coordinate(v7);
        \draw [green] (v6)--(v7);

        \draw
        (v0)++(1.8,1.5) coordinate(v8)
        (v8)--++(1,-0.3) coordinate(v9)

        (v9)--++(-1,-0.7) coordinate(v10)
        (v9)--++(-1,-0.4) coordinate(v11)

        (v9)--++(4,0.1) coordinate(v12)
        (v12)--++(4,0.5) coordinate(v13)

        (v13)++(0.5,-1.75) coordinate(v14) {}
        (v14)--++(0,3) coordinate(v15)
        (v15)--++(1,0) coordinate(v16)
        (v16)--++(0,-3) coordinate(v17)
        (v17)--++(-1,0) coordinate(v18)
        (v17)--(v18) node[pos=0.5,below=0.1cm]{Subestação 2}

        (v0)++(2.5,0.1) coordinate(v20)
        (v20)--++(1,0.3) coordinate(v21)
        (v21)--++(8,0.2)
        ;

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.} 
        \vspace{0.03\textwidth}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw
        (0,0) coordinate(v0) {} 
        (v0)++(0,2) coordinate(v2)
        (v2)++(2,0) coordinate(v3)
        (v3)++(0,-2) coordinate(v4)
        (v4)++(-2,0) coordinate(v5);
        \draw [blue] (v0)--(v2);
        \draw [blue] (v2)--(v3);
        \draw [blue] (v3)--(v4);
        \draw [blue] (v4)--(v5) node[pos=0.5,below=0.2cm]{Subestação 1};

        \draw
        (v0)++(4,3) coordinate(v6)
        (v6)--++(2,1) coordinate(v7)

        (v0)++(1.8,1.5) coordinate(v8)
        (v8)++(1,-0.3) coordinate(v9);

        \draw [green] (v8)--(v9);
        
        \draw
        (v9)--++(-1,-0.7) coordinate(v10)
        (v9)--++(-1,-0.4) coordinate(v11)

        (v9)--++(4,0.1) coordinate(v12)
        (v12)--++(4,0.5) coordinate(v13)

        (v13)++(0.5,-1.75) coordinate(v14) {}
        (v14)--++(0,3) coordinate(v15)
        (v15)--++(1,0) coordinate(v16)
        (v16)--++(0,-3) coordinate(v17)
        (v17)--++(-1,0) coordinate(v18)
        (v17)--(v18) node[pos=0.5,below=0.1cm]{Subestação 2}

        (v0)++(2.5,0.1) coordinate(v20)
        (v20)--++(1,0.3) coordinate(v21)
        (v21)--++(8,0.2)
        ;

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.} 
        \vspace{0.03\textwidth}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw
        (0,0) coordinate(v0) {} 
        (v0)--++(0,2) coordinate(v2)
        (v2)--++(2,0) coordinate(v3)
        (v3)--++(0,-2) coordinate(v4)
        (v4)++(-2,0) coordinate(v5)
        (v4)--(v5) node[pos=0.5,below=0.2cm]{Subestação 1}
        
        (v0) ++(1.5,0.4) coordinate(v6)

        (v6)++(2,-1) coordinate(v7)
        (v7)++(2,2) coordinate(v8)
        (v8)++(3,0.5) coordinate(v9);

        \draw [red] (v6)--(v7) node[red,pos=0.8,above=0.25cm]{Linha 1};
        \draw [blue] (v7)--(v8) node[blue,pos=0.8,below=0.7cm]{Linha 2};
        \draw [green] (v8)--(v9) node[green,pos=0.4,above=0.2cm]{Linha 3};

        \draw
        (v9) ++(-0.5,-2) coordinate(v10)
        
        (v10)--++(0,3) coordinate(v11) 
        (v11)--++(1,0) coordinate(v12)
        (v12)--++(0,-3) coordinate(v13)
        (v13)++(-1,0) coordinate(v14)
        (v13)--(v14) node[pos=0.5,below=0.1cm]{Subestação 2};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação por uma sequência de linhas de transmissão.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Duas formas possíveis em como uma ligação subestação - subestação pode ser feita no \glsxtrshort{osm}.}    
    \label{segmentoapossegmento}
\end{figure}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

I want the last subfigure to continue to the next page without being cut, how can i achieve that?

Comment: a figure is an unbreakable box you need to split it into smaller figures that fit on a page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted in a comment, the contents of a `figure` environment cannot be broken across pages. Now, since you employ the `subcaption` package, a straightforward fix is readily available: the `\ContinuedFloat` machinery. I suggest you insert

```
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption*{\figurename\ \thefigure, cont'd}
```

after the third (or fourth, depending on space available) `subfigure` environment.

Furthermore, as the graphical material is now broken across two pages, I would also recommend that you place the overall `\caption` statement at the top of the first `figure` environment rather than keep it at the bottom of the (now) second `figure` environment.

I've eliminated all tikZ-code for the following screenshot, in order to focus on the structure of the formatting problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazilian'?

\begin{document}
\lipsum % filler text

\begin{figure}[p!]
\caption{Duas formas possíveis em como uma ligação subestação - subestação pode ser feita no \glsxtrshort{osm}.}    
\label{segmentoapossegmento}

    \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figa}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.} 
        \label{segmentoapossegmento:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \vspace{0.02\textheight}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figb}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.} 
        \label{segmentoapossegmento:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \vspace{0.02\textheight}
    
    \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figc}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.} 
        \label{segmentoapossegmento:c}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption*{\figurename\ \thefigure, cont'd}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figd}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação apenas por uma linha de transmissão.}
        \label{segmentoapossegmento:d} 
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \vspace{0.02\textheight}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fige}
        \caption{Uma subestação pode estar ligada a outra subestação por uma sequência de linhas de transmissão.}
        \label{segmentoapossegmento:e}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\lipsum % more filler text

\end{document}
```